# BTS tree search function C++

Tags: c++, csv, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

This program reads a CSV file and enters it into a binary search tree. So far I have managed to insert a new node, put it in order, however, internally, perform a search asking for the Varibale Key but I have not managed to get it to work, could someone help me?

The CSV file is reading a file that includes:
1, name1,123456
2, name2,165151
3, name3,1566516

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct Person {
  int key;
  std::string name;
  int num;
};

struct Node : Person {
  Node(const Person &person) : Person(person) {}
  std::unique_ptr<Node> left, right;
  void insert(const Person &person);
};

void Node::insert(const Person &person) {
  /* recur down the tree */
  if (key > person.key) {
    if (left)
        left->insert(person);
    else
        left = std::make_unique<Node>(person);
  } else if (key < person.key) {
    if (right)
        right->insert(person);
    else
        right = std::make_unique<Node>(person);
  }
}

std::vector<Person> persons;

void inorder(Node *root) {
  if (root) {
    // cout<<"\t";

    inorder(root->left.get());
    std::cout << '\t' << root->key << ' ' << root->name << ' ' << root->num << '\n';
    inorder(root->right.get());
  }
}

Node *minValueNode(Node *node) {
  Node *current = node;

  /* loop down to find the leftmost leaf */
  while (current && current->left) current = current->left.get();

  return current;
}


int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<Node> root;
  std::ifstream fin("data.txt");
  if (!fin) {
    std::cout << "File not open\n";
    return 1;
  }

  std::string line;
  const char delim = ',';

  while (std::getline(fin, line)) {
    std::istringstream ss(line);
    Person person;
    ss >> person.key;
    ss.ignore(10, delim);
    std::getline(ss, person.name, delim);
    ss >> person.num;
    if (ss) persons.push_back(person);
  }

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << std::setw(5) << persons[i].key << std::setw(20)
              << persons[i].name << std::setw(15) << persons[i].num << '\n';
    if (!root) root = std::make_unique<Node>(persons[i]);
    else root->insert(persons[i]);
  }

  std::cout << "\n\nInorder:\n";
  //    cout<<node.name;

  inorder(root.get());

  return 0;
}
```

---

```
/*bool busqueda(Node *root, int dato)
{

    if(root){
    return false;
    }
    else if(root->key==dato){
        return true;
    }
    else if(dato<root->key){
       busqueda(root->left.get(),dato);
    }
    else{
        return busqueda(root->right.get(),dato);
    }

   }*/
```

---

Comment: Glad to see usage of `std::unique_ptr` here. Is there some reason you're not using `std::map` for this, though?

Comment: It had worked well for me until I tried to implement the search it seems that it is not compatible, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that this is the function you need help with:

```
bool busqueda(Node *root, int dato) {
    if(root){
    return false;
    }
    else if(root->key==dato){
        return true;
    }
    else if(dato<root->key){
       busqueda(root->left.get(),dato);
    }
    else{
        return busqueda(root->right.get(),dato);
    }
}
```

There are a few issues here:

```
if(root) {
```

This is testing if `root` is *not* `nullptr`, so you're going to immediately bail if `root` points at something.  Meaning, you will immediately return false if *any* tree is provided, which is the *opposite* of what you want.  Even worse, if `root` *is* null you will proceed and try to dereference a null pointer, which will crash the program.  Change this line to `if (root != nullptr) {`.

```
else if(dato<root->key){
    busqueda(root->left.get(),dato);
}
```

This recursive call looks right except *you don't return the result* meaning that you will reach the end of a function returning `bool` without actually returning anything meaningful.  Just add `return` before this function call.

You can mostly express this function using boolean logic as well:

```
bool busqueda(Node *root, int dato) {
    return root != nullptr && (
        root->key == dato ||
        busqueda((dato < root->key ? root->left : root->right).get(), dato)
    );
}
```

This makes it impossible to forget to return something.

As a side note, enable all compiler warnings -- it would have warned you about reaching the end of a non-void function without returning a value.

Comment: I appreciate the help however I have tried what you tell me and it gives me the same error, it seems that bool is not compatible with Unique_ptr, but I cannot do it in any other way, any other idea?

Comment: @Erick Can you give a specific compiler error? I'm not sure what you mean by "not compatible with unique_ptr."

Comment: error: cannot convert 'std::unique_ptr<Node>' to 'Node*' for argument '1' to 'bool busqueda(Node*, int)'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: Any other form that could be implemented to request the search?

Comment: @Erick You just need to call `.get()` on the `unique_ptr` to extract the raw pointer when you call `busqueda()` -- just like you were already doing within `busqueda()`.